# Write-SqlTableData to import CSV into a Azure SQL Server table

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

The below command creates a new table, `test` for me but it doesn't insert any data into it.

```
Write-SqlTableData -TableName test -ServerInstance myservername -DatabaseName mydb -SchemaName dbo -Credential $mycreds -InputData $data -Force
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Write-SqlTableData : Cannot access destination table '[Mydb].[dbo].
[test]'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-SqlTableData -TableName test -ServerInstance myinstance
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: ([dbo].[test]:Table) [Write-SqlTableData], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WriteToTableFailure,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.WriteSqlTableData
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is the code to populate data.

```
 $data = import-csv 'C:\Users\azure-user\myfile.csv'
```

This is what the file looks like -

```
"State","ProviderNbr","Entity","Address","City","Zip","Phone","Ownership","StarRating"
"AL","017000","ALABAMA DEPARTMENT OF HEALTH HOME CARE","201 MONROE STREET, SUITE 1200", "ALABAMA", "32423", "3233233233", "Alabama", "4"
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to populate `$data`

Comment: I assume you have read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08a48832-fb67-45df-b891-365fa3baef81/powershell-writesqltabledata-error?forum=ssdsgetstarted) - seems you can pipe the data directly instead of using an intermediate variable.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I have updated my question with the code I am using to populate data.

Comment: Have you tried piping it directly into the write command as per the example I posted?

Comment: Maybe a user permission problem ? Check the SQL Server log / Event Viewer

Comment: @DaleBurrell Yes. I tried this, but same result - `Write-SqlTableData -TableName test -ServerInstance myservername -DatabaseName mydb -SchemaName dbo -Credential $mycreds -InputData @{ 01='abc'; 02='xyz'} -Force`

Comment: @Max My user is a db_owner.

Comment: Double check the Event Viewer on SQL Server machine. SQL Server write a more detailed error on EV.

Comment: @Max This is an Azure SQL database. I do not think it gives us access to Event Viewer on there.

Comment: Updated title and tags

Comment: By `pipe` I was referring to this syntax `,(Import-Csv -Path ".\a.csv" -Header "Id","Name","Amount") | Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "MyServer\MyInstance" -DatabaseName "MyDatabase" -SchemaName "dbo" -TableName "CSVTable" -Force` where you don't use the `-InputData` at all.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Yes, I have tried that. It gives me the same error. I think it is because of `Write-SqlTableData`. So it looks like as long as that is in the command, I am going to continue to receive that error.

Comment: @DaleBurrell @Max I am able to read the table using `Read-SqlTableData ` but not able to write to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we can not use the command `Write-SqlTableData` to import CSV file to Azure SQL and we just can use it to import CSV file to on-premise SQL
[image]

So if you want to import CSV file to Azure SQL with powershell, you can use the command `Invoke-SQLCmd`to insert record on by one. For example:

```
$Database   = ''

$Server     = '.database.windows.net'

$UserName   = ''

$Password   = ''

$CSVFileName = ''

 $text = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Colors2](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](30) NULL
) "
Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance  $Server  -Database $Database -Username $UserName -Password $Password -Query $text

 $CSVImport = Import-CSV -Path $CSVFileName
 ForEach ($CSVLine in $CSVImport){

 $Id =[int] $CSVLine.Id
 $Vaule=$CSVLine.value
 $SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Colors2] (id, value)
VALUES('$Id', '$Vaule');"
 Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance  $Server  -Database $Database -Username $UserName -Password $Password -Query $SQLInsert


 }


Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance  $Server  -Database $Database -Username $UserName -Password $Password -Query "select * from [dbo].[Colors2]"
```

Besides, you also can use other ways ( such as BULK INSERT ) to implement it. For further information, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=azuresqldb-current.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird one - as you say, in Azure Read-SqlTableData works but Write-SqlTableData doesn't. From the discussion on [MSDN here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08a48832-fb67-45df-b891-365fa3baef81/powershell-writesqltabledata-error?forum=ssdsgetstarted) I think its something to do with the Azure environment making it hard for the cmdlet to interpret the 'ServerInstance' parameter.

Example 5 in Microsoft's [Write-SqlTableData documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) "*Write data to an existing table of an Azure SQL Database*" shows the way forwards - we need to instantiate an SMO reference to the Table and feed that to the cmdlet instead. Unfortunately the example Microsoft gives contains a small error (you can't do `$table = $db.Tables["MyTable1"]` to get the table, it doesn't work)

Here's a modified version of that example:

```
$csvPath = "C:\Temp\mycsv.csv"
$csvDelimiter = ","

# Set your connection string to Azure SQL DB.
$connString = 'Data Source=server;Persist Security Info=True'
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your SQL Auth credentials"
$cred.Password.MakeReadOnly()
$sqlcred = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential -ArgumentList $cred.UserName,$cred.Password

# Create a SqlConnection and finally get access to the SMO Server object.
$sqlcc = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList  $connString,$sqlcred
$sc = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection -ArgumentList  $sqlcc
$srv = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $sc

# Get access to table 'MyTable1' on database 'MyDB'.
# Note: both objects are assumed to exists already.
$db = $srv.Databases["MyDB"]
$tableSmo = $db.Tables | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "MyTable1"}

# leading comma makes an array with one item
# this makes PowerShell pass the entire contents of the file directly to the Write-SqlTableData cmdlet, which in turn can do a bulk-insert
, (Import-Csv -Path $pcsvPath -Delimiter $csvDelimiter) | Write-SqlTableData  -InputObject $tableSmo 

$sc.Disconnect()
```

If you're doing integrated security you can miss off all the $cred and $sqlcred stuff and just create the SqlConnection using `$sqlcc = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList  $connString`

Note: This worked for me with "A SQL Server running on a VM in Azure", in that I was having the same error as you, 'cannot access destination table' and this approach fixed it. I haven't tested it with an "Azure SQL Database" i.e. SQL Server as a service. But from the microsoft documentation it sounds like this should work.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post your answer. I will try it out and see if it works.